# why I got Wrong training result with changing forward function in VAE?

Tags: python

I have a VAE model with the below forward function and loss function:

```
def forward(self, x):
        mu, logvar = self.encode(x.view(-1, 2))
        z = self.reparameterize(mu, logvar)
        return self.decode(z), mu, logvar

def loss_function(recon_x, x, mu, logvar):
       L2 = torch.mean((recon_x-x)**2)
       KLD = -0.5 * torch.mean(1 + logvar - mu.pow(2) - logvar.exp())
    return L2 + KLD
```

the result of training for the multivariate gaussian dataset is similar to the photo below:
[image]

To do something, I changed the forward and loss function as follows

```
def forward(self, x):
        mu, logvar = self.encode(x.view(-1, 2))
        z = self.reparameterize(mu, logvar)
        q0 = torch.distributions.normal.Normal(mu, (0.5 * logvar).exp())
        prior = torch.distributions.normal.Normal(0., 1.)
        log_prior_z = prior.log_prob(z).sum(-1)
        log_q_z = q0.log_prob(z).sum(-1)
        return self.decode(z), log_q_z - log_prior_z

def loss_function(recon_x, x, KL):
    L2 = torch.mean((recon_x-x)**2)
    return L2 + KL
```

but the training result is as follows

[image]

How do I make these changes to get the same training result?

Comment: Why does your original `forward` function return 3 variables, and the new `forward` function returns only 2?

Comment: because I want to add PlanarFlow, and the way  I can  do that needs this forward function with 2 outputs